# Adding geometry to a three.js mesh after render

Tags: dynamic, geometry, three.js, mesh

I'm creating a mesh with a THREE.Geometry instance, then populating the geometry's `vertices` and `faces` arrays dynamically. The geometry is iteratively refined, adding additional vertices and faces at each iteration. If I refine the geometry before adding the mesh to the scene, it renders correctly. However, if I add the mesh to the scene and render it, then modify it, only the initial N faces the geometry contained on first render are shown. Changes to the position of the vertices used by those faces are honored, but only those N faces are rendered.

The geometry instance is marked `dynamic = true`, and I set `verticesNeedUpdate`, `elementsNeedUpdate` and `buffersNeedUpdate` each time after modifying the geometry. I've also tried setting all the other 'dirty' flags, though I only expect to need to set those three (and even then, I'm not certain I should need buffersNeedUpdate).

As far as I can see, the geometry's `geometryGroup` and `geometryGroupList` properties are being built and populated from the faces that exist when the mesh is first rendered, but are not being rebuilt to include the faces added subsequently.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you are using `WebGLRenderer`.

As stated in the three.js wiki article [How to Update Things](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates), you can only update the content of buffers, you cannot resize buffers.

three.js r.59

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen that page, thanks. So basically this is unsupported. I can't really pre-allocate buffers in this case, as I don't know in advance how large they would need to be. At this point, I'm removing the mesh from the scene and instantiating a new mesh+geometry on each render, which works but probably isn't very efficient... I'll have to think about a way to pre-allocate in blocks and only re-create the geometry when I pass the pre-allocated buffer sizes, or something.

Comment: Hey -- I'm doing something similar. I'm wondering, did you ever figure this out? Thanks @lharper71!

Comment: @C.Windolf [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36426139/incrementally-display-three-js-tubegeometry/36439563#36439563) related answer and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399856/drawing-a-line-with-three-js-dynamically/31411794#31411794) similar answer may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley! Really helpful answers