# Add geometry faces/vertices

Tags: three.js

I got a 2D Hexagon in my init()-Code, works well. I push 6 vertices and new faces, but nothing appear. Why?

for-loop:

```
    b.world.grid[x][z].Model.geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(b.world.grid[x]       [z].Model.geometry.vertices[i].x,b.world.grid[x][z].Model.geometry.vertices[i].y,b.world.grid[x]        [z].Model.geometry.vertices[i].z));

    b.world.grid[x][z].Model.geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 7));
```

I already used VerticesNeedUpdate

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842521/adding-geometry-to-a-three-js-mesh-after-render/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this code:

```
b.world.grid[x][y].Model.geometry.groupsNeedUpdate = true;
```

You need to update the group, not the `vertices` array, because the existing vertices haven't changed — you have just added some more, but you need to update the group of your existing model.

Comment: Save me lot of time (this is something referenced nowhere in documentation). Thanks