# Dynamic update of particle system

Tags: three.js

The current examples of particle systems are showing a static set of elements (vertices) that are initialized before the first rendering. But how can i dynamically add new vertices during the rendering process?

Examples: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_particles_random

I tried to set the update property but it didn't work during the update process.

```
 geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

In this way, i would like to add a new vertex at runtime.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842521/adding-geometry-to-a-three-js-mesh-after-render/

Comment: This is true. Thanks for the link.