# Incrementally display three.js TubeGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, spline

I am able to display a THREE.TubeGeometry figure as follows[image]

Code below, link to [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hazudebiba/edit?html,js,output)

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r75/three.js"></script>

<script>
    // global variables
    var renderer;
    var scene;
    var camera;
    var geometry;

    var control;

    var count = 0;
    var animationTracker;

    init();
    drawSpline();

    function init()
    {
        // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        // create a render, sets the background color and the size
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColor('lightgray', 1.0);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
        camera.position.x = 0;
        camera.position.y = 40;
        camera.position.z = 40;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        // add the output of the renderer to the html element
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    }

    function drawSpline(numPoints)
    {
        var numPoints = 100;
//        var start = new THREE.Vector3(-5, 0, 20);
        var start = new THREE.Vector3(-5, 0, 20);
        var middle = new THREE.Vector3(0, 35, 0);
        var end = new THREE.Vector3(5, 0, -20);

        var curveQuad = new THREE.QuadraticBezierCurve3(start, middle, end);

        var tube = new THREE.TubeGeometry(curveQuad, numPoints, 0.5, 20, false);
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(tube, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({
            opacity: 0.9,
            transparent: true
        }));

        scene.add(mesh);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I would like to **display incrementally**, as in, like an arc that is loading, such that it starts as the start point, draws incrementally and finally looks the below arc upon completion.

I have been putting in some effort, and was able to do this by storing all the points/coordinates covered by the arc, and drawing lines between the consecutive coordinates, such that I get the 'arc loading incrementally' feel. However, is there a better way to achieve this? This is the link to [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mosenipomu/edit?html,js,output)

Adding the code here as well

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Incremental Spline Curve</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r75/three.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<script>

    // global variables
    var renderer;
    var scene;
    var camera;
    var splineGeometry;

    var control;

    var count = 0;
    var animationTracker;

//    var sphereCamera;
    var sphere;
    var light;

    function init() {

        // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        // create a render, sets the background color and the size
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
//        renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1.0);
        renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 1 );
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
        camera.position.x = 0;
        camera.position.y = 40;
        camera.position.z = 40;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        // add the output of the renderer to the html element
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

//        //init for sphere
//        sphereCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
//        sphereCamera.position.y = -400;
//        sphereCamera.position.z = 400;
//        sphereCamera.rotation.x = .70;

        sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.8,31,31), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            color: 'yellow',
        }));

        light = new THREE.DirectionalLight('white', 1);
//        light.position.set(0,-400,400).normalize();
        light.position.set(0,10,10).normalize();

        //get points covered by Spline
        getSplineData();
    }

    //save points in geometry.vertices
    function getSplineData() {
        var curve = new THREE.CubicBezierCurve3(
                new THREE.Vector3( -5, 0, 10 ),
                new THREE.Vector3(0, 20, 0 ),
                new THREE.Vector3(0, 20, 0 ),
                new THREE.Vector3( 2, 0, -25 )
        );

        splineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        splineGeometry.vertices = curve.getPoints( 50 );

        animate();
    }

    //scheduler loop
    function animate() {
        if(count == 50)
        {
            cancelAnimationFrame(animationTracker);
            return;
        }

        //add line to the scene
        drawLine();

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
  //      renderer.render(scene, sphereCamera);

        count += 1;
//        camera.position.z -= 0.25;
//        camera.position.y -= 0.25;
        animationTracker = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    function drawLine() {
        var lineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x0000ff
        });
        console.log(splineGeometry.vertices[count]);
        console.log(splineGeometry.vertices[count+1]);
        lineGeometry.vertices.push(
                splineGeometry.vertices[count],
                splineGeometry.vertices[count+1]
        );

        var line = new THREE.Line( lineGeometry, lineMaterial );
        scene.add( line );
    }

    // calls the init function when the window is done loading.
    window.onload = init;

</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Drawback : The drawback of doing it the above way is that, end of the day, I'm drawing a line between consecutive points, and so I lose out on a lot of the effects possible in TubeGeometry such as, thickness, transparency etc.

Please suggest me an alternative way to get a smooth incremental load for the TubeGeometry.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`THREE.TubeGeometry` returns a `THREE.BufferGeometry`.

With `THREE.BufferGeometry`, you have access to a property `drawRange` that you can set to animate the drawing of the mesh:

```
let nEnd = 0, nMax, nStep = 90; // 30 faces * 3 vertices/face

...

const geometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry( path, pathSegments, tubeRadius, radiusSegments, closed );

nMax = geometry.attributes.position.count;

...

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    nEnd = ( nEnd + nStep ) % nMax;

    mesh.geometry.setDrawRange( 0, nEnd );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

EDIT: For another approach, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37091797/1461008).

three.js r.144

Comment: thanks so much, this is great. I spent some time trying to understand it and was able to tune to my liking (fiddle as next comment). I just had a couple of questions. Q1.I understand nMax = geometry.attributes.position.count What exactly is nMax? Has my geometry been converted to 24576 points? Do these points define the geometry I want to draw? In your fiddle, points.length==18 and nMax==245762. Q2.You mention in your comment that you assign nStep to be 90, because 30 faces * 3 vertices/face. I didn't get this, your fiddle looks like a small intestine, I don't see 30 faces. :)

Comment: Friendly tip: Study and understand `BufferGeometry`. It would be valuable for you to do that. Also study the fiddle so you understand every line of it. (1) `nMax` = total number of vertices (positions) in the buffer geometry. `points` is a temporary array used to define the curve. (2) `nStep` is now many extra vertices to draw each frame. In this case, 30 additional faces are rendered each frame. (2b) The faces are tiny. There are a lot of them. :)

Comment: @WestLangley nice example.but can we edit the curve points in renderer?i want to make a moving snake using keys.so curve points are not predictable.for example i'm looking for something like this with key controls http://oos.moxiecode.com/js_webgl/snake/

Comment: @FastSnail Please make a detailed post and ask the community if you need help.

Comment: @Zhenyuan-Li Sorry, I am not familiar enough with SO's policies to know whether your suggestions are appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would be able to use the method [.getPointAt()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/extras/core/Curve.getPointAt) to *"get a vector for point at relative position in curve according to arc length"* to get a point at a certain percentage of the length of the curve.

So normally if you want to draw 70% of the curve and a full curve is drawn in 100 segments. Then you could do:

```
var percentage = 70;
var curvePath = new THREE.CurvePath();

var end, start = curveQuad.getPointAt( 0 );

for(var i = 1; i < percentage; i++){
    end = curveQuad.getPointAt( percentage / 100 );
    lineCurve = new THREE.LineCurve( start, end );
    curvePath.add( lineCurve );
    start = end;
}
```

But I think this is not working for your `curveQuad` since the `getPointAt` method is not implemented for this type. A work around is to get a 100 points for your curve in an array like this:

```
points = curve.getPoints(100);
```

And then you can do almost the same:

```
var percentage = 70;
var curvePath = new THREE.CurvePath();

var end, start = points[ 0 ];

for(var i = 1; i < percentage; i++){
    end = points[ percentage ]
    lineCurve = new THREE.LineCurve( start, end );
    curvePath.add( lineCurve );
    start = end;
}
```

now your `curvePath` holds the line segments you want to use for drawing the tube:

```
// draw the geometry
var radius = 5, radiusSegments = 8, closed = false;
var geometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(curvePath, percentage, radius, radiusSegments, closed);
```

**[Here a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5yms2tsf/)** with a demonstration on how to use this dynamically

Comment: thanks a lot Wilt. I spent some trying to understand it, and then was able to make a few edits. JS fiddle : http://jsbin.com/gexexefalu/edit?html,js,output .Am I right in saying that the first time getGeometry is called,  only the first point is plotted, in the fifth time it draws line from 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5 and in the 70th time, say, it draws from 1-2, 2-3....69-70. So, are we redrawing the line from 1-2 70 times instead of making use of the line drawn in the previous iteration (or 'current') ? I understand it may not be optimized, this is just to clarify my understanding.

Comment: @PepperBoy indeed this code is not totally optimal, since the previous mesh (and geometry) is removed and totally redrawn in the next iteration. If you get yourself familiar with the BufferGeometry class and its setDrawRange method as mentioned in the accepted answer the solution is definately more optimized. My answer gets you a similar result without using the BufferGeometry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really that familiar with three.js. But I think I can be of assistance. I have two solutions for you. Both based on the same principle: build a new TubeGeometry or rebuild the current one, around a new curve.

**Solution 1 (Simple):**

```
var CurveSection = THREE.Curve.create(function(base, from, to) {
  this.base = base;
  this.from = from;
  this.to = to;
}, function(t) {
  return this.base.getPoint((1 - t) * this.from + t * this.to);
});
```

You define a new type of curve which just selects a segment out of a given curve. Usage:

```
var curve = new CurveSection(yourCurve, 0, .76); // Where .76 is your percentage
```

Now you can build a new tube.

**Solution 2 (Mathematics!):**

You are using for your arc a quadratic bezier curve, that's awesome! This curve is a parabola. You want just a segment of that parabola and that is again a parabola, just with other bounds.

What we need is a section of the bezier curve. Let's say the curve is defined by A (start), B (direction), C (end). If we want to change the start to a point D and the end to a point F we need the point E that is the direction of the curve in D and F. So the tangents to our parabola in D and F have to intersect in E. So the following code will give us the desired result:

```
// Calculates the instersection point of Line3 l1 and Line3 l2.
function intersection(l1, l2) {
  var A = l1.start;
  var P = l2.closestPointToPoint(A);
  var Q = l1.closestPointToPoint(P);
  var l = P.distanceToSquared(A) / Q.distanceTo(A);
  var d = (new THREE.Vector3()).subVectors(Q, A);
  return d.multiplyScalar(l / d.length()).add(A);
}

// Calculate the tangentVector of the bezier-curve
function tangentQuadraticBezier(bezier, t) {
  var s = bezier.v0,
      m = bezier.v1,
      e = bezier.v2;
  return new THREE.Vector3(
    THREE.CurveUtils.tangentQuadraticBezier(t, s.x, m.x, e.x),
    THREE.CurveUtils.tangentQuadraticBezier(t, s.y, m.y, e.y),
    THREE.CurveUtils.tangentQuadraticBezier(t, s.z, m.z, e.z)
  );
}

// Returns a new QuadraticBezierCurve3 with the new bounds.
function sectionInQuadraticBezier(bezier, from, to) {
  var s = bezier.v0,
      m = bezier.v1,
      e = bezier.v2;

  var ns = bezier.getPoint(from),
      ne = bezier.getPoint(to);
  var nm = intersection(
    new THREE.Line3(ns, tangentQuadraticBezier(bezier, from).add(ns)),
    new THREE.Line3(ne, tangentQuadraticBezier(bezier, to).add(ne))
  );
  return new THREE.QuadraticBezierCurve3(ns, nm, ne);
}
```

This is a very mathematical way, but if you should need the special properties of a Bezier curve, this is the way to go.

**Note:** The first solution is the simplest. I am not familiar with Three.js so I wouldn't know what the most efficient way to implement the animation is. Three.js doesn't seem to use the special properties of a bezier curve so maybe solution 2 isn't that useful.

I hope you have gotten something useful out of this.

Comment: thanks so much toonijn :) The math is great. Really appreciate the help. Just trying to get my hands dirty with three.js