# Animated THREE.TubeGeometry along path

Tags: three.js

Similar to this animation example, I'm trying to smoothly animate a tube as if it were drawn in a fast efficient way using three.

[image: example]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36426139/incrementally-display-three-js-tubegeometry/36439563#36439563

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incrementally display three.js TubeGeometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36426139/incrementally-display-three-js-tubegeometry)