# THREE.js: updating RingGeometry vertices

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, ring

I want to update a RingGeometry's vertices dynamically.
What I do is to create another RingGeometry and replace the first one's vertices with the vertices of the new one.

The problem is it was working fine on version 6.7 of THREE.JS, but on the latest version (8.9) it stopped working.

Snippet with version 6.7:

```js
scene = new THREE.Scene;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer;
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

counter = 0;
increase = Math.PI / 100;

render = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  angle = Math.PI * (Math.sin(counter) + 1) / 2; // avoid negatives
  counter += increase;
  ring = new THREE.RingGeometry(4, 5, 40, 1, 0, angle);
  mesh.geometry.vertices = ring.vertices;
  mesh.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

geometry = new THREE.RingGeometry(4, 5, 40, 1, 0, Math.PI * (Math.sin(counter)+1) / 2);
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffff00});
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

camera.position.z = 10;
renderer.render(scene, camera);
render();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs-socketio-basic.herokuapp.com/three67.js"></script>
```

Snippet with version 8.9:

```js
scene = new THREE.Scene;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer;
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

counter = 0;
increase = Math.PI / 100;

render = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  angle = Math.PI * (Math.sin(counter) + 1) / 2; // avoid negatives
  counter += increase;
  ring = new THREE.RingGeometry(4, 5, 40, 1, 0, angle);
  mesh.geometry.vertices = ring.vertices;
  mesh.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

geometry = new THREE.RingGeometry(4, 5, 40, 1, 0, Math.PI * (Math.sin(counter)+1) / 2);
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffff00});
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

camera.position.z = 10;
renderer.render(scene, camera);
render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/89/three.min.js"></script>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905929/three-js-2xmeshes-using-same-vector-as-position/26916159#26916159).

Comment: I think this is not the case. That answer applies to "position, rotation, quaternion and scale", and I'm updating the vertices in the geometry.

Comment: Sorry. It is not the best idea to instantiate a new geometry every frame, but if you do, copy the vertices values (rather than assign a new array) and set only the `verticesNeedUpdate` flag. Better approaches can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090564/how-to-animate-the-drawing-of-a-mesh-in-three-js/37091797#37091797

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after several hours of fiddling, I found the problem!

With the new version of THREE.js it needs the flag "elementsNeedUpdate = true;".

Working fiddle on version 8.9:

```js
scene = new THREE.Scene;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer;
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

counter = 0;
increase = Math.PI / 100;

render = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  angle = Math.PI * (Math.sin(counter) + 1.01) / 2; // avoid negatives
  counter += increase;
  ring = new THREE.RingGeometry(4, 5, 40, 1, 0, angle);
  mesh.geometry.vertices = ring.vertices;
  mesh.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  mesh.geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

geometry = new THREE.RingGeometry(4, 5, 40, 1, 0, Math.PI * (Math.sin(counter)+1) / 2);
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffff00});
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

camera.position.z = 10;
renderer.render(scene, camera);
render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/89/three.min.js"></script>
```